# Handle PUT like GET on Apache2

Tags: apache-2.2

When I request with `PUT`, I'm getting `405 Method Not Allowed`.

I've seen on Internet that `PUT` is for using with DAV. But I don't want to use DAV and I want to make `PUT` working like `GET`.

I tried with `Limit`, `LimitExcept`, `Rewrite`, on Linux and Windows.

I got PHP5 (i think it's not the filtered one), APACHE 2.2 and Ubuntu Server 12.04.

Thanks for help.

Comment: maybe this will help you?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934554/how-to-enable-and-use-http-put-and-delete-with-apache2-and-php

Comment: not working, 405 Method not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run a plugin or script that will actually handle PUT. The core of the server isn't willing to do that.

Comment: yes but, wich one?

Comment: Pick your language of choice and search the web. There's no popular third party module for this

Comment: actually I just want to make apache run PUT like GET

Comment: Yes, I understand you don't want to have to do anything but that's not how it works